# How to use new PhpSpreadsheet with ZF1

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Before PHP 7 I used PHPEXcel.
Now, I use PHP 7.4 and I must use PhpSpreadsheet inside my Zend Framework 1 web application.

that's mean, IMHO, not using composer, so my question is simple : How to ?

tried to use example inside my project, but not working

Answer (score 1):

The code in my public/index.php

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/fpdf'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/biffwriter'),  
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/editablegrid'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms'),  
    get_include_path(),
)));

/* PATH FOR FPDF (FONT)*/
define('FPDF_FONTPATH',APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/fpdf/font/');

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';  
require_once 'phpspreadsheet/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

The code in my ExportControllers

```
     * Export content in a XLSx file
     * @return 
     * @param object $content
     * @param object $filename
     */
    public static function exportAsXLSx($content, $filename, $parades, $resultat) 
      {     
        // $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        
        error_log("Creating Spreadsheet instance");
        $objPHPExcel = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        
        error_log("setting up properties");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Web BASCULE")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Web BASCULE")
                             ->setTitle("Extraction des données de WEB bascule")
                             ->setSubject(" ")
                             ->setDescription(" ")
                             ->setKeywords("Bascule ")
                             ->setCategory("Result file");
        
        error_log("setting up FONT");
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial')->setSize(10);
        
        error_log("setting up activeSHEET");
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        error_log("we are here");
```

I don't have any file and my php-fpm/www-error.log says Creating Spreadsheet instance and nothing else...